# Покажите на простом примере, в чем отличие интерполяции от экстраполяции?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, терминология

Мне сложно разобраться с методами мат. анализа посредством справочников. Правильно ли я понял в самом общем смысле, что такое интерполяция и экстраполяция:

```
interpolator = (array[i] + array[i+1]) / 2;
потом мы его суём между array[i] и array[i+1];

extrapolator = (array[i-2] + array[i-1] / 2);
и мы его суём на место уже array[i].
```

Код я набросал сам, как мог.. В качестве самого примитивного способа приближения значения точек выбрал арифметическое среднее между ними..

Comment: а откуда вообще эти формулы взялись?

Comment: В самом общем смысле интерполяция -  способ нахождения **промежуточных** значений величины по имеющемуся дискретному набору известных значений, а экстраполяция - попытка найти значения функции **вне** заданного интервала, а не между заданными значениями. Откровенно говоря, не понимаю, как можно совмещать нелюбовь к математике с программированием...

Comment: @Grundy Интерполяция, это приближенное значение между двумя точками, а экстраполяция -- это приближение вне этих точек.. Что-то такое, типа.. Только вот не вгрызу я толком, может кто и поможет..

Comment: Поможет учебник.

Comment: @KonstantinVolobuev, с определением понятно - а формулы-то откуда взялись?

Comment: Ребят, вы чего?? Формулки в справочнике, а тут я руками набросал самый примитивный пример..

Comment: Формулы не верные, экстраполяция и интерполяция это вообще то разложение по некоторому базису.

Comment: Интерполировать через среднее крайних значений ещё можно, но вот для экстраполяции делать такое - явная ошибка.

Comment: @Александр не успел написать :) да в целом можно и такое делать, все ведь зависит от вида исходных точек, и метод экстраполяции должен быть подходящим. Так что и среднее значениеможет быть подходящим.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов по какому базису и какое там разложение вобще ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Интерполяция**, это нахождение промежуточного значения между двумя известными, по какому-либо алгоритму. Ваш пример в общем верен:

```
// Например среднее арифметическое:
interpolator = (array[i] + array[i+1]) / 2;
// Располагаем между array[i] и array[i+1]
```

**Экстраполяция**, это нахождение следующего значения по известным предыдущим, по какому-либо алгоритму. Самый общий пример будет вот такой:

```
// Например линейное продолжение по 2 последним точкам:
extrapolator = (array[i-1] + (array[i-1] - array[i-2]));
// Располагаем на место array[i]
```

---

Алгоритмы могут быть самые разнообразные, от повторения значений, до аппроксимации по кривым и т.п. В целом алгоритмы могут быть похожи, но, обычно, экстраполяция более алгоритмически сложный процесс.

---

P.S. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К стати да, если бы я написал повторение точки: array[i+1] = array[i], меня бы вообще сожгли тут) Благодаря таким людям как вы математику поднимать в радость!)